# Isomorphism between modules over a semisimple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

If $P$ is a module over the semisimple ring $R/J$, where $R$ is a semilocal ring having $1$, and $J$ is its Jacobson radical, does any isomorphism $P⊕...⊕P≅P'⊕...⊕P'$ with the same (finite) number of  components each side lead to $P≅P'$? Any cooperation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to consider $J$; just assume $R$ is semisimple. Every (right) module over a semisimple ring is a direct sum of simple modules. Moreover, consider $(S_i)_{i\in I}$, a family of simple modules over $R$ such that

1. every simple $R$-module $S$ is isomorphic to $S_i$, for some $i\in I$;
2. if $i\ne j$, then $S_i$ is not isomorphic to $S_j$.

We can decompose every module $M$ as
$$
M=\bigoplus_{i\in I} S_i^{(\alpha_i)}
$$
where $N^{(\alpha)}$ means the direct sum of $\alpha$ (a cardinal) copies of $N$.

Then we can prove that
$$
\bigoplus_{i\in I} S_i^{(\alpha_i)}\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I} S_i^{(\beta_i)}
$$
if and only if $\alpha_i=\beta_i$, for all $i\in I$. This is a particular case of theorem 12.4 in Anderson-Fuller “Rings and Categories of Modules”.

Now, if $\alpha_i$ is infinite and $n>0$ is an integer, then $(S_i^{(\alpha_i)})^n\cong S_i^{(\alpha_i)}$; if $\alpha_i$ is finite, $(S_i^{(\alpha_i)})^n\cong S_i^{(n\alpha_i)}$. Thus your claim follows.

Alternatively one could use the more general Krull-Remak-Schmidt-Azumaya theorem that you find in [these notes](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDcQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783034803021-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1316849-p174271584&ei=maKMVMVa2PVqwOeCqAM&usg=AFQjCNHT07rN2PT7sO41n9rG63W04r8iZw&sig2=R-e8ZeOnIws2EnMUPaBXzw&bvm=bv.81828268,d.d2s&cad=rja) as Theorem 2.12.